# Tensorflow Convert .pb file to .lite file in windows using python

Tags: python, windows, tensorflow

When I am trying to convert .pb file to .tflite file by following the instruction on Tensorflow for poet : https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/tensorflow-for-poets-2-tflite/#2

I am getting `No module named 'tensorflow.contrib.lite.python.tflite_convert'`

My Tensorflow version: `1.10.0`

I tried running two commands but it is resulting the same error:

**Command 1:** `tflite_convert --graph_def_file=rounded_graph.pb --output_file=new_graph.lite --input_format=TENSORFLOW_GRAPHDEF --output_format=TFLITE --input_shape=1,224,224,3 --input_array=input --output_array=final_result --inference_type=FLOAT --input_data_type=FLOAT`

**Command 2:** `toco --input_file="rounded_graph.pb" --output_file="new_graph.lite" --input_format="TENSORFLOW_GRAPHDEF" --output_format="TFLITE" --input_shape="1,224,224,3" --input_array="input" --output_array="final_result" --inference_type="FLOAT" --input_data_type="FLOAT"`

I am getting this error in `windows`.

Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I solved this problem on windows:

1. Open CMD
2. Run : `pip install --upgrade pip`
3. Then, Run : `pip install tensorflow --upgrade`

My New Version of **Tensorflow** : `1.13.0`

Then using this link: https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/tensorflow-for-poets-2-tflite/#2

Try run the following **command** : `tflite_convert --graph_def_file=rounded_graph.pb --output_file=new_graph.lite --input_format=TENSORFLOW_GRAPHDEF --output_format=TFLITE --input_shape=1,224,224,3 --input_array=input --output_array=final_result --inference_type=FLOAT --input_data_type=FLOAT`

If you get any error in **input** try changing the `input` names and the `input_shape`

Comment: Should the input_shape be the same no matter what? or is it something to consider?

Comment: I am getting 12576 illegal hardware instruction